# Jquery отказывается работать

Tags: javascript

Вот есть код в чате с формой и отправкой аякс запроса по нажатию на кнопку.
НО увы ничего не происходит.
КОД ОТПРАВКИ

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#send").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'chat_result.php',
            data: 'type=send&text=' + $('#text').val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#text").val("");
            }
        });
    });
    setInterval(getContent, 100);
</script>
<?php
echo '<div class=c><form method="post">
<textarea id="text" name="text" row=3 placeholder=Сообщение style="width: 100%;"></textarea><br><input id="send" type="button" value="Окей" class="button"></form></div>';
?>
```

КОД ОБРАБОТЧИКА

```
    <?php
include('../sys/config.php');
if($_POST['type']=='send'){
if($_SESSION['flud']<time()){
$text=text($_POST['text']);
if(empty($text)) msg('Пустое смс!');
else{
$_SESSION['flud']=time()+10;
q("INSERT INTO `chat` SET `avtor`='".$user['id']."',`text`='$text',`komu`='".text($_SESSION['i'])."',`status`='1',`time`='".time()."'");
unset($_SESSION['i']);
//header('Location: chat.php');
//exit();
}
}else msg('Нельзя писать так часто!');
}
?>
```

Помогите разобрать пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент вызова `$("#send").click(` кнопки `send` еще нет.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#send").click(function() {
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Благодарю вас!!